# Can Jssor support percentage width?

Tags: jssor

I just want to make a fullscreen slideshow with Jssor. But it seems to me the container's width and images' width must be fixed but not percentage. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, jssor slider doesn't support percentage width.

What you can do is to make a percentage width div container, and then put jssor inside the container. As jssor slider always scales to fit the parent container, it will meet your needs.